# Exception: Signal only works in main thread, python, tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, signals

Well, I'm making application in tkinter and for my background process I'm using threads, so that my application who get freezed while performing a background process.

But, I it giving me the exception. The line bot.login() is giving the exception.

Below is the code.

```
from tkinter import * 

import threading 

from instabot import Bot


def login_thread():
    threading.Thread(target=login).start()

def login():
    # pb = progress_bar()
    # pb.start()
    username = username_variable.get()
    password = password_variable.get()

    try:
        canvas.delete('usernameTag')
        canvas.delete('passwordTag')
        canvas.delete('invalidLoginTag')
    except:
        pass

    cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
    try:
        os.remove(cookie_del[0])
    except Exception:
        pass

    if username == '':
        username_error()
        # pb.stop()
        # pb.unpack()
        
    elif password == '':
        password_error()
        # pb.stop()
        # pb.unpack()
        
    else:
        try:
            print("hi")
            bot.login(username=username,password=password)
            print('hello')
            # pb.stop()
            # pb.unpack()
            unpack_login_panel()
            acc.pack(username)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            invalid_login()
            # pb.stop()
            # pb.unpack()


b0 = Button(
    image = img0,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = login_thread,
    relief = "flat")

b0.place(
    x = 760, y = 453,
    width = 550,
    height = 43)
```

This is giving me the exception that, signal only works in the main thread. btw, this is just a small part of the code.
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Why do you think you need a thread here? What you trying to do wont work. Either you forget about the thread and leave the code like this or you rearrange it and just do a worker thread that dosent interferes the main thread. There are a couple of questions on this site to help you understand this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just missing an optional argument

bot.login(is_threaded = True)